# How to handle special characters in URL with Flask

Tags: python, url, web, flask

I am using Flask to develop a mini API backend, I have following URL:

```
@app.route('/v1.0/post/check/<path:url>')
def check(url):
    print url
    //do some works
```

A sample API call looks like:
`/v1.0/post/check/http://exampleside.com/enter1/index.php?app=forum&act=threadview&tid=14066185`

What I expected is to get and print URL string `'http://exampleside.com/enter1/index.php?app=forum&act=threadview&tid=14066185'` in the code, but in fact, what I really get is only `'http://exampleside.com/enter1/index.php'`

Seems Flask considers '?' and '&' as special chars and then split a URL automatically. So what I should do in order to get the URL as a whole in Flask?

Comment: So do you need to save the entire URL or are you trying to extract the parameters?

Comment: @Chris Chambers  I want to get parameter <path:url>, but print the entire URL is also ok as I can anyway extract the url parameter from it.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to pass a url, including request parameters on a url.

You have two choices.

The smart one is to urlencode that part of the URL when you construct it. That will safely encode the ? and & symbols.

Here is an example so you can tell whether it's so. This:

```
Foo?g=one&two=2
```

will look like this:

```
Foo%3Fg%3Done%26two%3D2
```

That will be the last segment of the uri for your api.

The second one is to reconstruct the value from all the arguments flask splits up. But that strikes me as a lot of work.

Comment: I am using Chrome to test, so I just paste the API call in the browser, I think it is urlencoded already by Chrome?

Comment: seems chrome doesn't do the urlencoding job for me, it works after I explicitly encoded the url. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ? and & indicate that you are receiving parameters in the URL.

To get them, you need to use the request object like so:
`app = request.args.get('app')`

If you just want the whole url, parameters and all, try Robert's method.

Comment: I tried 'whole_url = request.args.get('app')        print whole_url'  then I get None